# Java Swing - Use the cursor of a sibling component instead of the parent's?

Tags: java, swing

By default, if a swing component doesn't have a cursor set, it uses the cursor of it's parent.

Is it possible to change so that the component uses the cursor of a sibling component instead?

In my application I have a JLayeredPane, with two overlapping JPanels inside of it. One is a transparent overlay on top, the other is a solid regular panel underneath. I would like the cursor in the overlay to be the one corresponding to the solid regular JPanel (the sibling). However, the cursor used by default is the cursor of the JLayeredPane (the parent).

How do I make the overlay uses the cursor of the solid JPanel?

Example:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestCursor {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(400, 400);

            // The JFrame holding everything.
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            // The JLayeredPane.
            JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
            layeredPane.setPreferredSize(dim);
            frame.add(layeredPane);

            // The panel with the color and hand cursor.
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            panel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
            panel.setSize(dim);

            // The invisible panel
            JPanel transpPanel = new JPanel();
            transpPanel.setOpaque(false);
            transpPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
            transpPanel.setSize(dim);

            // Add the two panels. The cursor is not the hand cursor.
            layeredPane.add(transpPanel, -1);
            layeredPane.add(panel, -1);

            frame.pack();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding `public Cursor getCursor() {...}` so that it returns the desired object?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I make the overlay uses the cursor of the solid JPanel?

You have answered your own question:

> if a swing component doesn't have a cursor set, it uses the cursor of it's parent.

Well you haven't stated why you can't just set the cursor for the layered pane so that both of the children use the same cursor.

So before suggesting more complicated solution I would suggest you can use:

```
layeredPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
```

Or, the other option would be to set the cursor for both panels.

A few other comments:

```
layeredPane.add(transpPanel, -1);
layeredPane.add(panel, -1);
```

Don't use magic numbers. People don't know what -1 means.

Also, the point of using a layered pane is to assign each component to a different layer. So if you want the transparent panel on top then you would use something like:

```
layeredPane.add(transpPanel, Integer.valueOf(2));
layeredPane.add(panel, Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Also, since the panel is non-opaque, there is no need to set the background color to a value with transparency:

```
transpPanel.setOpaque(false);
//transpPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `contains(x,y)` for the transparent frame:

```java
  @Override
  public boolean contains(int x, int y)
  {
    for (Component component : getComponents()) {
      Point containerPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this,x, y,component);
      if (component.contains(containerPoint)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```